# Turbowarp's project_url parameter doesn't work

Tags: github, mit-scratch

Wanted to upload a project to turbowarp anonymously

When I tried to load the [page](https://turbowarp.org/?project_url=github.com/FoxOfNine/foxgod.fnaf.io/blob/main/fnaf.sb3) it just shows this error on the screen:

Oops! Something went wrong.

We are so sorry, but it looks like the page has crashed. Please refresh your page to try again.

TypeError: Failed to fetch
Component stack: in vI in Connect(vI) ...

The github url still works perfectly, the file is fine when I tried downloading it. Is it just too heavy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.